# Timthumb isn't displaying any images. "A TimThumb error has occured

Tags: apache, cache, linux

I have a Wordpress web site which is hosted on a distributed infrastructure. I have a web server(apache) and a cache server (varnish). When I load the site directly from web server everything is OK, but when I load the site from the cache, I sometimes get the following error:

```
Timthumb isn't displaying any images.

"A TimThumb error has occured
```

I saw some answers about this problem which mainly point out to the file permissions. But I don't get any error related to permissions!! any help is appreciated.

Comment: Timthumb is insecure, and has known exploits, you should not use it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I moved a wordpress site to CloudWays which used varnish.  I had to find the varnish configuration section and specifically exclude the timthumb.php script from varnish. This solved my issue because each call to timthumb.php to resize an image must be processed and it cannot be cached.  I hope this helps you... I realize this question is old.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this in the future configurations.